# Arduino GSM SIM900 does not receiving messages

Tags: arduino, sms, gsm, sim900

Following URL will be appear my GSM module and it is included data sheet of the SIM900 module.

http://www.pennybuying.com/gsm-gprs-module-sim900-development-board-lbs-mms-support-arduino-uno-ttl-rs232.html

I have connected only RX,TX,GND and PWR pin between GSM module and Arduino mega board.
Sending a SMS is work properly but receiving SMS is doesn't work.

This is the Arduino Code of sending sms - (Reference - http://tronixstuff.com/2014/01/08/tutorial-arduino-and-sim900-gsm-modules/)

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM900(15,14);

char incoming_char=0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(19200); // for serial monitor
  SIM900.begin(19200); // for GSM shield
  SIM900power();  // turn on shield
  delay(20000);  // give time to log on to network.

  SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");  // set SMS mode to text
  delay(100);
  SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r"); 
  // blurt out contents of new SMS upon receipt to the GSM shield's serial out
  delay(100);
}

void SIM900power()
// software equivalent of pressing the GSM shield "power" button
{
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  delay(7000);
}

void loop()
{
  // Now we simply display any text that the GSM shield sends out on the serial monitor
  Serial.println("loop");
  if(SIM900.available() > 0)
  {
     Serial.print("waiting");
    incoming_char=SIM900.read(); //Get the character from the cellular serial port.
    Serial.print(incoming_char); //Print the incoming character to the terminal.
    while(1){};
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `SIM900.print("AT+CMGD=1,4\r");` in your `setup()`. I faced similar problems and the reason was that sim-card memory for messages is full.

You wont get any messages or notification if there is no space in sim memory!

So your setuo loop would look like this

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(19200); // for serial monitor
    SIM900.begin(19200); // for GSM shield
    SIM900power();  // turn on shield
    delay(20000);  // give time to log on to network.

    SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");  // set SMS mode to text
    delay(100);
    SIM900.print("AT+CMGD=1,4\r");  // Deletes all SMS saved in SIM memory
    delay(100);
    SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r"); 
    // blurt out contents of new SMS upon receipt to the GSM shield's serial out
     delay(100);
}
```